# Weave Unable to decrypt TCP msg

Tags: connection, weave

Struggling with this for a couple of days.  Unable to connect a desktop to a weave network. Error:

```
connection shutting down due to error during handshake: Unable to decrypt TCP msg.
```

Other instances are able to connect using the same command:

```
weave launch --ipalloc-init observer --ipalloc-range 10.36.0.0/16 --password something  --trusted-subnets 10.1.1.0/16 ipToConnectTo
```

The desktop had been moved to another subnet 10.1.6.0 and used to have a reservation at 10.1.3.26.  We changed the reservation to 10.1.6.23 and rebooted the desktop.  I have a feeling this is more of a network issue rather than a problem with weave and could use some help from some network gurus.

OS - Mint 19, docker verson - 18.09.0, and weave - 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Was the password...the hand written password lower 'k' looked like a 'K'.